# Trying to get Month-Year from Date in SSRS while using Query

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, reporting-services

I've been trying to get Month-Year from the Date.

My code is

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, adempiere.c_invoice.dateinvoiced, 0))    
FROM adempiere.c_invoice
```

The error that i get when i Edit as Text is

```
An error occured while executing the query.
ERROR [42703] ERROR: column "month" does not exist;
Error while executing the query

Additional information: ->
Error [42703] Error: column "month" does not exist; Error while executing the query (PSQLODBC.DLL
```

When im in the query designer in data server tools and i "Run SQL"

The program automatically adds (") to the Month becoming "Month" and adds "AS Expr1" behind. It becomes like this

```
SELECT        DATEADD("MONTH", DATEDIFF("MONTH", 0, adempiere.c_invoice.dateinvoiced, 0)) AS Expr1
FROM            adempiere.c_invoice
```

And the error is

```
SQL Execution Error

Executed SQL statement: SELECT DATEADD("MONTH", DATEDIFF("MONTH", 0, adempiere.c_invoice.dateinvoiced, 0)) AS Expr1
FROM adempiere.c_invoice
Error Source: PSQLODBC.DLL
Error Message: ERROR [42703] ERRPR: Column "MONTH" does not exist;
Error while executing the query
```

thanks so much for reading and hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Month(adempiere.c_invoice.dateinvoiced)+"-"+ DATEPART(year,adempiere.c_invoice.dateinvoiced)  
   FROM adempiere.c_invoice
```